# Proof that two square, diagonal matrices A and B fulfill the first binomial formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In the current exercise for linear algebra, we had to find conditions so that two arbitrary quadratic matrices A and B with the same dimension satisfy the first binomial formula:

(A+B)^2 = A^2 + 2AB + B^2

While we do not need to prove our solution, I'm still interested in proving my own, which goes as follows:

It seems obvious to me that they need to be diagonal matrices, which becomes even clearer if you write down two general square and diagonal matrices with the same dimension and make some general calculations. But I'm interested in proving it with mathematical rigour.

So far, I thought about writing the binomial formula in this case in the form of the matrix components, which should look like this:

((a *ij*)(b *ij*))^2 = (a *ij*)^2 + 2(a *ij*)(b *ij*) + (b *ij*)^2

I thought maybe I could deduce my heuristic assumption for the condition from this form of the equation. If you have any idea on how I could deviate the proof from this or if you have           an entirely different approach, I'd be happy if you would share it with me. And again, it's not mandatory for us to do it, but I would like to...

Thanks in advance and have a nice day,

SDV

Comment: The obstruction to this being satisfied is the matrix $(A+B)^2 - (A^2 + 2AB + B^2)$; if you actually expand this out and simplify, what do you get?

Comment: diagonal matrices commute.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
(A+B)^2=AA+AB+BA+BB=A^2+AB+BA+B^2.
$$
What you want to know is: under what circumstances does
$$
A^2+AB+BA+B^2\overset{?}{=}A^2+2AB+B^2.
$$
By subtracting $A^2+B^2$ from each side, you can see that this is equivalent to asking that
$$
AB+BA=2AB,
$$
or
$$
BA=AB.
$$
So, in order for this to be true, it must be the case that $A$ and $B$ [*commute*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices). The case where $A$ and $B$ are diagonal matrices certainly works: it is not hard to check that diagonal matrices commute, by writing out how the multiplication of those matrices works.  However, there are many, many non-diagonal matrices $A$ and $B$ which work here as well.

Comment: Best answer on it.